# How can I change the name of a data series in a bar chart?

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm new to SSRS and I am struggling with a very simple task.  I just want to change the name of a data series in a bar chart. The data value for the data series is an expression (=Sum(IIf(Fields!HCC.Value = "N", Fields!PlanPaidMbr.Value, Nothing))

SSRS is automatically naming it 'Plan Paid Mbr', but I want to name it 'HCC'. Here are some screenshots of my situation. Why is this so difficult to do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you right click on the column in the chart and select series properties, select ledged and you can enter in the name you want

Comment: you should add this as an answer - you can answer your own questions. SO is all about helping others, so even if you answer you own question and mark it as accepted, it helps other people form answers the similar questions.